# Why is a quasicrystal characterized by a distribution for which it and its Fourier Transform both have only discrete supports?

Tags: fourier-transform

Why does a distribution where both it and its Fourier Transform have discrete supports characterize a quasicrystal (an ordered but aperiodic structure) ?

Comment: Because it is the natural generalization of the Dirac comb and other discrete periodic distributions ?

Comment: Ah, then am I misinterpreting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Quasicrystals when it says "...a quasicrystal, meaning a distribution with discrete support whose Fourier transform also has discrete support." , since a Dirac comb is also a distribution that fits this description was is not aperiodic? Or is Wiki wrong here?